# Segue not running after MPC viewcontroller is dismissed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an action tied to pop up the MPC view controller however once this action is complected and the browser is dismissed I simply am lead back to my old view controller

```
func browserViewControllerDidFinish(
browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController!)  {
    // Called when the browser view controller is dismissed (ie the Done
    // button was tapped)
    func seguetoJoin(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var joinView: playMusicViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! playMusicViewController
         weak var delegate: MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate!

    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be calling dismissViewController on the VC that is receiving the didFinish callback.

You should move the segue code to the ViewController that needs to perform the segue, rather than performing it on a ViewController that is being dismissed.

Also, these are unused

```
var joinView: playMusicViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! playMusicViewController
weak var delegate: MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate!
```

> Update -

Following the comments below.

> in mpcSubClass.m
>   var viewControllerToPeformSegue: UIViewController!

```
func browserViewControllerDidFinish(browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController!)  {
    // animation:false as your segue will have an animation
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    self.viewControllerToPerformSegue.handleBrowserDidFinish()
}
```

in viewControllerToPerformSegue.m

```
// when you initialise the MPC VC subclass
mpcVCSubclass.viewControllerToPerformSegue = self

func handleBrowserDidFinish()
{
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainViewSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) 
{
     if segue.identifier == "mainViewSegue"
    {
        let mainVC = segue.destination as! MainVC
        // now pass any data to your main VC that it can load in viewWillAppear
    }
}
```

> in storyboard

link viewControllerToPerformSegue to the MainVC and name the segue mainViewSegue

Hope this helps.

Comment: the     
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) 
was already put there by default, however with only that there it simply dismisses the view controller and sends us back to the previous screen instead of advancing forward to a third view controller.

Comment: If you would like to segue from this view, call performSegue in that call back and remove the dismissViewController: call

Comment: and what would the identifier and sender be in that situation?

Comment: This all depends on your architecture. Do you have a navigation controller? Do you want the browser view to perform the segue, is the segue in the storyboard, the identifier would be the one from the storyboard. The sender is the ViewController that is performing the segue, so the browser VC if you want it to.

Comment: alright so I added this 

     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainScreen", sender:self)

and I keep getting a crash when I click done in my viewcontroller, any ideas, I have named my viewcontrollers storyboard ID to "mainscreen" from the main.storyboard

Comment: Did you name the identifier for the segue in the storyboard? You need to select the segue itself, and name it, otherwise the perform method cant find "mainScreen" as a segue. E.g. call you segue mainScreenSegue and pass that to the perform method. If its not that, post the crash summary please.

Comment: there is no way to select the segue in the storyboard because the segue in the storyboard because no view controller appears in the storyboard as it is a premade view controller
I assigned the identifier to the final view controller as I had no idea where else to put it and this was the error

Comment: _Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property_

Comment: "Premade", meaning loaded from a xib file? Then you cant perform a segue from it. Segues work in storyboards. If the viewcontroller that pushes this browser view is in the storyboard, move the segue call into that class. Create a weak property (to avoid circular reference) to it inside the browser VC. Then after the dismiss call, you call the weak property, which internally can call the perform segue. Seems like a UX issue here.

Comment: As for the constraints error, thats a different question

Comment: Im not sure if premade as in loaded from a file, but inside of the Multipeer Connectivity Framework it supplies its own view controller to connect devices, is that the same thing?

Comment: Ok, so they handle the presentation and give you the callback to dismiss. If you view controller is the delegate for the MPC, then you can connect your view controller to the next one in the storyboard, name the segue and use that. You wouldnt call dismissViewController here. If you subclassed the MPC VC then you need the weak reference to your VC, so that you can tell it to perform the segue just after the dismissVC call in the subclass.

Comment: Could you maybe ELI5 that? sorry I'm new to swift

Comment: I can update my answer but could you tell me if the class with the didFinish method is a subclass of the MPC VC or is it a delegate callback in another VC? If its a delegate callback, is this VC the one you want to perform the segue to the next one and is this one already in the storyboard?

Comment: it is a subclass of MPC